# Angular form element in separated component gives FormGroup error

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-forms

I have a form element made with Angular Material which is a autocompleted country selectbox:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Country" aria-label="Number" matInput formControlName="country" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
  <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option">
      {{ option.name }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

In the `ngOnInit` I call an API and this populates the filteredOptions.

Since I am going to use this picker in many forms I want to make a component of it. As soon as I move the code to a component I got:

> SelectCountryComponent.html:2 ERROR Error: formControlName must be
>   used with a parent formGroup directive.  You'll want to add a
>   formGroup
>          directive and pass it an existing FormGroup instance (you can create one in your class).

Even though I use my component in a FormGroup it still gives this error. What would be the right approach to create a component which contains a formControl?

**select-country.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-select-country',
  templateUrl: './select-country.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./select-country.component.css']
})
export class SelectCountryComponent implements OnInit {

  countryFormGroup = new FormGroup({
    country: new FormControl('')
  });

  options: Country[];
  filteredOptions: Observable<Country[]>;

  constructor(public api: ApiService) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.api.get('country').subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res);
      this.options = res;
      this.filteredOptions = this.countryFormGroup.get('country').valueChanges.pipe(
        startWith<string | Country>(''),
        map(value => (typeof value === 'string' ? value : value['name'])),
        map(name => name ? this._filter(name) : this.options ? this.options.slice() : [])
      );
    });

  }

  displayFn(country?: Country): string | undefined {
    return country ? country.name : undefined;
  }

  private _filter(name: string): Country[] {
    const filterValue = name.toLowerCase();

    return this.options.filter(
      option => option.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue) === 0
    );
  }

}
```

**select-country.component.html**

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Country" aria-label="Number" matInput formControlName="country" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
  <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option">
      {{ option.name }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case:

```
<form [formGroup]="countryFormGroup" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <mat-form-field>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Country" aria-label="Number" matInput formControlName="country" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

You need to bind countryFormGroup with form by `[formGroup]="countryFormGroup"` and use `formControlName` inside it.

To make your code cleaner, you can filter options using pipe in HTML

Comment: Thanks, what kind of filter are you thinking of?

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your mat-form-field in a **div** or **form** with [formGroup]="countryFormGroup". You need to bind the instantiated formGroup to the template.

```
<div [formGroup]="countryFormGroup">
<mat-form-field>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Country" aria-label="Number" matInput formControlName="country" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
  <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option">
      {{ option.name }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
</div>
```

Comment: Also, to note, since you are only using one FormControl in the FormGroup of this component, you can forego the use of the FormGroup altogether and simply use [(ngModel)] or I think using [formControl] vs. formControlName may be a clean option as well.

Comment: Can you post a working example of using [formControl] ?